# configuring a file shortcut (.lnk) to add command line options to a file to be opened by VLC

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I want to start `VLC` in `Windows 10` with a certain video file playing, starting at a certain time-stamp.

Per this link: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Jump_to_a_certain_time/

this can easily be done via the Command Line, like so:

```
% vlc --start-time=83.4 --stop-time=300 BigBuckBunny.ogv
```

However, I want to do this via a file shortcut (`.lnk`) to VLC player

E.g., in the below folder, I have 2 files.

[image: screen capture of a folder view with 2 files in it]

`vlc.exe.lnk` is a shortcut `.lnk` file that points to `vlc.exe` elsewhere. When I double-click on it, it opens up VLC player.

When I double-click on `vlc.exe.lnk`, I want to open up `independence.mp4` starting at the 10 second mark.

I was under the impression that in a `.lnk` file, if I entered the Command Line Options in the `Right-Click/Properties/Target` text field (after the target file), then it would open the target file with the command line options. However this is not happening as expected here.

[image: right click / properties view of vlc.exe.lnk]

Details:

vlc.exe location: `"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\portable\video\VLCPortable media player\App\vlc\vlc.exe"`

video file location: `"C:\Users\user.name\Downloads\Videos\independence.mp4"`

What I modified the `Right-Click/Properties/Target` text field to:

```
"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\portable\video\VLCPortable media player\App\vlc\vlc.exe" --start-time=10 "C:\Users\user.name\Downloads\Videos\independence.mp4"
```

However, this is not working.

I've tried things like removing the double quotations from around the video file name, and removing the `--start-time` flag altogether, but neither worked.

Thoughts on what I should try to get this to work?

Comment: does your command work from the command line? if so try it from a .bat and point your .lnk to the bat.

Comment: @FrankThomas -- thank you, that worked.